# Data structure when submitting in Firestore that handles tracking of inventories with product variations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Each product may have variations of sizes and each with its different colors and quantities.

Example:

- **Product Name: Shirt**
- Size: Large
- Color: Red, Qty: 10
- Color: Blue, Qty: 5
- **Product Name: Cupp**
- Size: Large
- Color: Red, Qty: 10
- Color: Blue, Qty: 5

The way I submitted it and what shows in the console:

[image]

Code:
Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-order-working-4f6g2

**Firestore:**

[image]

Comment: Can you specifically mention what is the difficulty you are facing while doing it?

Comment: @Prabir like will this be plausible since I'll be subtracting the stocks as well?

Comment: What is the Firestore database structure? Can you post a screenshot of the Firestore Database from the Firebase console?

Comment: @Prabir Added it in the post

Comment: What did it mean when you said `you want to know if it possible`? Do you want to know if it is possible to update the `colorStocks` field?

Comment: @Prabir yes, if it's possible to do update the colorStocks. I've also stored it as a number instead of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have the ability to update an existing element in an indexed array. It supports only two methods, `arrayUnion()` to add an element and `arrayRemove()` to remove an element from the array as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

As an alternative, you can read the entire array out of the document, make modifications to it in memory, then update the modified array field entirely. This is an error prone and tedious process. You can have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) to know more about it.

I am not sure of your use case, but it seems you can make your database structure more suitable by using maps(nested objects) instead of arrays. Something like this -

[image]

By doing this you can update the nested objects by dot notation as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects). Some sample to update the document will look like this -

```
async function updateData(color) {
 const docRef = doc(db, 'collectionId', 'documentId');
 await updateDoc(docRef,{
   [`colorStockList.${color}`]:300
 });
}
```

**UPDATE**

To update the stocks automatically you can implement a method which will get invoked when an order is placed. Within that method you can use the `increment()` method as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects). The `increment()` method can increase or decrease the stocks based on the value provided by you. For example if someone places an order for 3 shirts you can pass that number to the `increment()` method so that it can decrease the stocks by that value. Make sure to use **-ve** sign with the value when you want to decrease the stocks.

The method should look something like this -

```
async function updateData(color,value) {
  const docRef = doc(db, 'collectionId', 'documentId');
 await updateDoc(docRef,{
   [`colorStockList.${color}`]:increment(-value)
 });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've changed the firestore data structure. It's similar to the example you gave. I read about in firestore a distributed counter to increment and decrement the fields. Would it work?

Comment: The purpose of a distributed counter is something different. In Cloud Firestore, you can update a single document only once per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic applications. If you need to update your counter above this rate, that is when you can use a distributed counter. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: so it's not possible to reduce the stocks of the `red` automatically? Because every time an order is placed, the stocks will be reduced automatically

Comment: Yes, it is possible to update automatically. For that you can implement some method like I have mentioned in the answer. And when an order is placed you can invoke the method which will update the stocks. You can use the increment() method as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Comment: so what if I'll choose the same product and I wanted the colors red, blue, and black. Can I still update the product automatically by using increment (-1)? Whenever I'll place an order, there might be instances where I need to place 2 kinds of products and each would have different colors, would this still be possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that. For that you probably have to implement more than two methods in your code and from there invoke the updateData method while iterating over the list of the products with colors and numbers.

Comment: I'll have to implement something like a loop that would access the document ID of the product and update the quantities of the colors?

Comment: Yes, you can do in that way and update the stocks.